# What word means "to be an indicator of"?

Tags: word-request

I am writing a paper and have got a result. This result is very much like what I am trying to prove, so I want to say

> *this result is [**something**] of*

I am sure there is a better way of putting it than *this result is an indicator of*, but I can't quite remember it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of *indicative*?

> [indicative](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indicative)
>    adjective
>   1.showing, signifying, or pointing out; expressive or suggestive (usually followed by of):
>   *behavior indicative of mental disorder.*
>   (Dictionary.com)

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I didn't think of this, thanks very much :)

Comment: It happens! Good luck.